# How to design two separated menus in a mobile first design?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a web application with 2 separated menus (main menu and sub menu).
The idea is to put the main menu onto the left while the submenu is on the top (this is the current design of this application which isn't mobile friendly at all, but it should stay that way for desktop screens).

So the following image shows the desktop frame design:

1. Header
2. Main Menu
3. Sub Menu
4. Content

[image: Desktop frame design]

The idea for a mobile design was the following:

[image: Mobile frame design]

So the main menu and the sub menu are both hidden by default and pop up when you hit the menu button on the top left and it overlaps the content (so the content is not only on the right side, it uses the full width and height under the header).

I don't come up with an idea how to combine those two designs in a clean way. I don't want to duplicate any elements which toggle between the different screen sizes but I am not sure if this is even possible (hence this question).

If it makes a difference: I don't mind if in the desktop design the main menu uses the full height and the header uses the same width as the sub menu and the content.

Can someone help me figuring out if this is possible without using ugly/dirty hacks in JS or something (we have blind users of our application, so it should make sense for a screen reader)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love these type of problems to solve.
Here is a simple html for the markup:

```html
<div class="page open">
  <header>1</header>
  <main>
    <nav>2</nav>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <section>4
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam, ipsum, at iusto magni sunt alias porro tempora nam, aut ex dignissimos doloribus. Dolorem reprehenderit suscipit sunt eum ut itaque dolores.
      Illum laborum impedit voluptates ipsum est quod esse? Nihil distinctio ullam non aperiam maiores dolor explicabo quidem magnam ex, nemo unde iusto nisi a temporibus ab modi, autem dolore magni.
      Voluptatem magnam quod aperiam laudantium qui sit ipsa, veniam suscipit optio ducimus? Ipsam, et. Temporibus odio mollitia neque maxime necessitatibus et debitis quaerat assumenda quis eveniet consequatur laudantium, adipisci excepturi.
    </p>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
```

in the css you can playing around with the `position` properties, but in this example, the menu will overflow on the whole page if its works for you.

```css
:root{
  --header-height: 80px; /* magic number */
  --main-menu-width: 120px; /* magic number */
  --sub-menu-height: 100px; /* magic number */
}
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.page{
  position: relative;
}
header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  height:var(--header-height);
}
main{
  padding-top: calc(var(--header-height) + var(--sub-menu-height));
  padding-left: var(--main-menu-width);
}
p{
  font-size:120px;
}
nav{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: var(--header-height);
  height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height));
  width: var(--main-menu-width);
  background-color: #999999;
}
.sub-menu{
  position: fixed;
  top: var(--header-height);
  left: var(--main-menu-width);
  width: calc(100% - var(--main-menu-width));
  height: var(--sub-menu-height);
  background-color: #ededed;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  main{
    padding-top: var(--header-height);
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  nav{
    height: calc(calc(100vh - var(--header-height)) / 2);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    left: calc(var(--main-menu-width) * (-1));
  }
  .sub-menu{
    width: var(--main-menu-width);
    height: calc(calc(100vh - var(--header-height)) / 2);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    left: calc(var(--main-menu-width) * (-1));
    top: calc(calc(calc(100vh - var(--header-height)) / 2) + var(--header-height));
  }
  
  /* Add open class to the body to open menu on mobile */
  .open nav,
  .open .sub-menu{
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is a working responsive [pen](https://codepen.io/Tyutyesz/pen/GRxQrdW) .

Hope it will help

Comment: This is brilliant. Started playing around with it and it is already a good start.
The only thing I forgot to mention: I don't know the height of the main menu as it has a variable amount of items (depending on the roles of the user). But it seems it is not possible to calculate this height dynamically.